# inheritance compile time or run time?

Tags: c++, inheritance, runtime, compile-time

In c++, does inheritance occur at run time or compile time?

Examples?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: i was asked this in an interview?

Comment: You might want to mention things like that next time. People generally don't appreciate it when askers seem to come up with <cough>not-so-intelligent</cough> (ill-posed) questions for no apparent reason. "I was asked this in an interview, and to my surprise, I couldn't really figure out what they intended" would take the problem out of that.

Comment: @haris: That's believable.  It's a valid question, IMO, but it's a remarkably vague question... the kind you could spend minutes answering.

Comment: @haris if you were asked this in an interview, the interviewer probably expects you to explain to him how you can't answer this question, and why.

Comment: +1 With half of the answers to this Q being Incorrect I now think this is indeed a good Question :)

Comment: Inheritance doesn't "occur" any more than an integer "occurs".

Answer (score 7):

In C++, ***inheritance in itself*** (*without polymorphism*) ***is a compile-time feature***. In the compiled code, there will be little or no difference between

```
struct foo : bar {};
```

and

```
struct foo { bar b; };
```

Except for offsets to access their members, there will not be any "knowledge" about how `bar` relates to `foo` in the compiled binary.

---

This is different, however, ***when you add polymorphism*** (i.e., `virtual` functions, allowing `dynamic_cast<>()`) to the picture. It allows *late binding*: which exact function will be called is decided at runtime. Of course, this requires data structures to perform this (usually employing so-called *virtual tables*), and those data structures are ***accessed at runtime*** in order to determine which function to call.

Also, ***`virtual` base classes*** require runtime support in order to access them withing derived objects.

---

If you are interested in the runtime costs of certain C++ features, you might want to try to get hold of a copy of ***[Inside the C++ Object Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545)*** by Stanley Lippman. It's an old book, but if you want to know how virtual member functions are commonly implemented and how base objects are commonly laid out in memory in a multi-inheritance scenario, and how all this affects performance, this is where you will find thorough discussions of such topics.

Comment: Apt to add Nothing is run-time unless there is a `virtual` keyword lingering somewhere even in case of Inheritance.

Comment: @Als: That seems a bit too broad to me. A `for` loop certainly is a pure runtime feature, despite it not being `virtual`.

Comment: @sbi: Indeed.*Everything* in this case should be limited to *functions* and *classes*. +1 BTW, because this is the only correct clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

In simplest terms,

The keyword `virtual` specifies whether the compiler or the runtime should do the lifting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "occurs"... it is defined at compile time but executed at run time (vtables etc).

Comment: Actually, virtual tables are a mechanism to implement polymorphism, and you can have inheritance without polymorphism.

Comment: Nothing is run-time unless there is a `virtual` keyword lingering somewhere.The answer is incorrect and misleading.

Answer (score -1):

There are techniques that implement inheritance at both compile and run time.